# The difference between Task.Run and TaskFactory.StartNew？

Tags: c#

```
        Task.Run((() => ))

        new TaskFactory().StartNew((() => ))
```

What's the difference between them?

I wonder what the difference is

Comment: Or try reading the _Remarks_ section of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew?view=net-7.0

Comment: Thank you very much. That's what I want